# mouseenter/mouseout makes div flicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, mouseenter, mouseout

I have a tooltip that shows on the mouseenter event and hides on the mouseout event. Sometimes, not always, when the mouse moves within the image for the tooltip the tooltip flickers. How can i prevent this happening? Is there a better way to do this?

Here is my code:

```
$('#home_pic').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#home_tip').show();
});
$('#home_pic').mouseout(function() {
    $('#home_tip').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use mouseleave instead of mouseout()

```
$('#home_pic').mouseleave(function() {
    $('#home_tip').hide();
});
```

Or use .hover

```
 $('#home_pic').hover(function() {
        $('#home_tip').hide();
    },function() {
        $('#home_tip').show();
    });
```

Comment: I was just noticing that Ankit!  I was like, "generally, doesn't a +1 comment come with a +1 upvote?"  It's also worth noting that the .hover just calls mouseenter and mouseleave.

Comment: i know hover calls mouseenter and leave but it reduce code size

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `toggle()` function for this, it accepts a boolean to set the state, so something like:

```
$('#home_pic').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $('#home_tip').toggle(e.type==='mouseenter');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tz7pw/)

Comment: I liked this approach. +1 (real one)

Answer (score 0):

Try mouseleave instead of mouseout like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/tncbbthositg/dWKfX/

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your mouseenter and mouseleave functions in a proper way, something like below:

```
$('#home_pic').mouseenter(function() {
    $("#home_pic").show();
},mouseleave(function() {
    $("#home_pic").hide();
}));
```

Note: Code Not tested to work.

Comment: $(this) won't refer to the correct div.  Notice the hover div is different from the tooltip div.

Comment: edited the piece, thats why I make sure to put code not tested.

Comment: So,it should still be #home_tip in your code.  Also, you're passing the result of the mouseleave function as the handler to mouseenter in this case.  I think this is what you're looking for:  $('#home_pic').mouseenter(function() {
    $("#home_tip").show();
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $("#home_tip").hide();
});​

Answer (score 0):

you can also try something like this if the tooltip runs over the home pic - I've used very similar code to pop up bubbles on a image map

```
$('#research_area').mouseover(function() {
$('img#research').css('display', 'block');
runthis();
});



function runthis () {
if ( $('img#research').css('display') == 'block')  {
$('img#research').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
    });
}
```

http://www.karpresources.com/